# AzureAD Authentication for a blazer web assembly hosted app, already created without CLI

Tags: visual-studio, authentication, azure-active-directory, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor web assembly hosted app which was created without CLI (thru VS UI). Now I want to build in authentication with Azure AD. I registered the client and server app, but in the sever and client code, I am missing lot of ready code that would be present if it was created with CLI with option -au. Example, some supporting code in program.cs, Login razor page, etc.
Can I manually add the missing code, or is there a way I can bring it in at this time automatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already created a Blazor WebAssembly Hosted app with the Microsoft identity platform as authentication type like below then the pages are readily  configured with required pages  and you just need to make small changes to add in placeholders of the app registration details.

Otherwise, you need to create a new application from scratch with the Microsoft identity platform as authentication type and copy all the folders and files of your app. Or you will have to try changing the authentication type and dependenciesif possible .

[image]

Changes to be made if you have already created/have a Blazor WebAssembly Hosted app with the Microsoft identity platform as authentication type

- Change Application url In launchsettings.json to required port
- Give all values in plcaeholders  in  server’s appsettings.json file:

```js
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xyz.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": " ",
    "ClientId": "",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
    },
```

**client side:**

- In appsetting.json add authority and client id in respective places

```html
    "AzureAd": {
            "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenatId> ",
            "ClientId": "",
            "ValidateAuthority": true
        }
```

- Add this dependency
  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication` by
  installing through nuget package and using it in app.

If you cannot change the authentication type , then you need to install the required libraries(microsoft.identity.web) in the app and do all configurations manually.

**References:**

1. You can refer  [this blog](https://code-maze.com/using-azure-active-directory-to-secure-blazor-webassembly-hosted-apps/) for more information about those small changes and
   dependencies to be added.
2. [ASP.NET Core and Blazor Code Venture: Configuring Azure AD
   Authentication (vmsdurano.com)](https://vmsdurano.com/asp-net-core-and-blazor-code-venture-configuring-azure-ad-authentication/#serversideblazorauthenticationwithazuread)